# Секции в ассмблере и процессоре

Tags: ассемблер, x86-64

Я правильно понимаю что в процессоре нет подобия тех секций, которые есть в ассемблере (text, bss, data). Я говорю про архитектуру amd64, хотя может в других есть?

Comment: в некоторых случаях (встроенные системы напр.) секция может быть назначена при компоновке какому-нибудь блоку памяти, например text в программный flash

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Да, вы правы. Эти секции являются частью формата исполняемых файлов и используются операционной системой при загрузке программы в память. Архитектура amd64, как и большинство других архитектур процессоров, не имеет таких секций.

Comment: Можете что-то порекомендовать к прочтению про то как ОС использует эти секции?

Answer (score -1):

> Я правильно понимаю что в процессоре нет подобия тех секций, которые есть в ассемблере (text, bss, data)

Секция - это блок памяти ОЗУ определённого размера. Когда процессор работет в реальном режиме RM, то секции называют сегментами. Поэтому у процессора нет секций, но зато есть шесть сегментных регистра `CS/DS/SS/ES/FS/GS` *(code,data,stack,extra,+2extented)*, при помощи которых ОС назначает **"атрибуты защиты"** этим секциям.

В реальном режиме MS-DOS модель памяти "сегментная" с макс.размером 1 сегмента =64 КБ - здесь из атрибутов только размер. В защищённом режиме модель автоматически меняется на "плоскую Flat" *(виртуальную)*, с макс.размером секции =4 ГБ (для х32). Тут уже в игру вступают **"селекторы и дескрипторы"** в сегментных регистрах, битовые поля в которых определяют атрибуты доступа к секциям, например `RO/RW/RWE` (Read-Only, Read-Write, Read-Write-Execute).